# Typed Zod combinator with dynamic field name

Tags: typescript, zod

My XML to JSON library emits `{MyKey: T}` for one-element lists, and `{MyKey: T[]}` for multi-element lists. The corresponding TypeScript type is `type XmlJsonArray<T, element extends string> = Record<element, T | T[]>`. I've used the following to implement it as a Zod schema:

```js
const XmlJsonArray = <T, element extends string>(element: element, schema: z.Schema<T>) => {
  // TODO what is the idiomatic approach here?
  const outerSchema: Record<element, z.Schema<T | T[]>> = {} as any;
  outerSchema[element] = z.union([schema, z.array(schema)]);
  return z.object(outerSchema);
};
```

Is there a way to do this without using `any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via [@vriad](https://github.com/vriad/zod/issues/211):

> ```
> const XmlJsonArray = <Key extends string, Schema extends z.Schema<any>>(
>   element: Key,
>   schema: Schema,
> ) => {
>   return z.object({}).setKey(element, z.union([schema, z.array(schema)]));
> };
>
> const test = XmlJsonArray('asdf', z.string());
> ```
>
> Parsing works as expected:
>
> ```
> // both work
> test.parse({ asdf: 'hello' });
> test.parse({ asdf: ['hello'] });
> ```
>
> And type inference works too:
>
> [image]